# Monoid how to use mempty

Tags: haskell

I have following datatype, that is implemented in `Monoid` typeclass:

```
data Optinal a = 
    Nada
  | Only a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Optinal a) where
  mempty = Nada
  mappend Nada (Only a) = Only a
  mappend (Only a) Nada = Only a
  mappend Nada Nada = Nada
  mappend (Only a) (Only b) = Only (mappend a b)
```

My question is, how to use `mempty` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mempty` in a `Monoid` defines the "unit" element. One particular scenario in which it might be used is if we had a function that aggregates over a list of `Monoid`s:

```
aggregate :: (Monoid a) => [a] -> a
aggregate [] = mempty
aggregate (x:xs) = x `mappend` aggregate xs
```

Remember that `Monoid`s are an abstraction over common forms of computation. When you write general functions for `Monoid`s, that's where `mempty` may show up.